# Is it possible to absorb energy from solar flares

Tags: energy, solar-flares

I've learnt that solar flares have so much energy in them, but is it possible to tap the energy from them?

Comment: Some problems in doing so would be: their unpredictability in when they occur & their resultant strength. In trying to utilise an energy source  the more predictable and consistent an energy source the better.

Comment: not now and it isn't so much of energy, comparing to amount of energy sun emits in more usual way. It possible, but not worth of efforts.

Comment: @MolbOrg but I've learnt that it has the power of one million atom bombs...

Comment: Energy of Sun, in form of light and heat, measured in atom bombs (I do not know which one, but let say 1Mt) is equivalent to 91300191204 atom bombs. So flares are less then 1/90000 of energy produced. Energy which you might extract at any scale with primitive approaches and any possible amount of it, starting with magnifying glass, or just sheet of reflective material. Scale needed to collect flares energy, with that scale you will get 90000 burgers instead one. But problem are not burger but energy you need to build that structure, and when you collect light heat you will grow well.

Answer (score 1):

Two scientists, Brooks L. Harrop and Dirk Schulze-Makuch, have hypothesized that a solar wind satellite built with the right proportions can generate an upwards of 1 billion billion gigawatts of energy(see pt. 5 below). The satellite's main components consist of a copper wire, receiver, and a sail. The satellite's charged copper wire, aimed at the sun, would create a magnetic field to snatch these highly charged particles coming from the sun. The particles that are captured are then directed towards the satellite's receiver unit, which produces a usable current. This self-sustaining satellite would divert energy generated into powering its magnetic field and the remaining energy would go on to power a laser that would aim at energy bases on Earth. The drained particles fall onto the sail and are soon recharged by the sun and propel the satellite through the particle's repulsion of magnetic fields.

[image]

The disadvantages of this system lie within transporting the energy captured back to earth. One idea is to use a concentrated laser beam to send the energy back to Earth. But,  there is several millions miles separation between satellite and Earth making it difficult for the laser beam to reach the planet without diffracting and losing energy. Also, with the current technology, there are no lenses powerful enough to direct a laser towards earth.

While solar wind will likely be a contender for source of renewable energy in the future, we lack the technology to develop something that will actually harness this energy, so for the time being, we have to stick with other existing source of energy.

**Notes and References**:

1. Harrop, B., & Schulze-Makuch, D. (2010). The Solar Wind Power Satellite as an alternative to a traditional Dyson Sphere and its implications for remote detection. International Journal of Astrobiology, 9(2), 89-99. doi:[10.1017/S1473550410000066](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/international-journal-of-astrobiology/article/solar-wind-power-satellite-as-an-alternative-to-a-traditional-dyson-sphere-and-its-implications-for-remote-detection/DF6FBB8CDCA6C74B31EEF900494497DA)
2. http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2015/ph240/camarena1/ (picture source)
3. https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn19497-out-of-this-world-proposal-for-solar-wind-power/
4. https://www.groundsure.com/resources/solar-wind-power/
5. 300 meters of copper wire, attached to a two-meter-wide  receiver and a 10-meter sail
   would generate enough power for 1,000 homes. So, a satellite with a 1,000-meter cable
   and a sail 8,400 kilometers across, placed at roughly the same orbit, would generate one billion billion gigawatts of power.

Comment: Does this answer address solar *flares* in any way?  Fascinating info though.